# Convert Kinect Beta code to version 1.5

Tags: c#, vb.net, sdk, kinect

Hi I have this method for a project I am doing with the Kinect. Unfortunately the code is the beta version and I need to update it to the 1.5 sdk version. I tried a few things but they wont work. Here is what I have to so far. The method is called nui_DepthFrameReady.

```
 void nui_DepthFrameReady(object sender, ImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!savedDepth)
        {
            PlanarImage Image = e.ImageFrame.Image;
            byte[] convertedDepthFrame = convertDepthFrame(Image.Bits);

            depth.Source = BitmapSource.Create(
                Image.Width, Image.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, convertedDepthFrame, Image.Width * 4);

            ++totalFrames;

            DateTime cur = DateTime.Now;
            if (cur.Subtract(lastTime) > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
            {
                int frameDiff = totalFrames - lastFrames;
                lastFrames = totalFrames;
                lastTime = cur;
                frameRate.Text = frameDiff.ToString() + " fps";
            }

            if (subscribed)
            {
                //byte[] ColoredBytes = GenerateColoredBytes(e.ImageFrame);
                //create an image based on the colored bytes
                BitmapSource myBitmapDepth = BitmapSource.Create(Image.Width, Image.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, convertedDepthFrame, Image.Width * PixelFormats.Bgr32.BitsPerPixel / 8);
                string imageFilePath = @"C:\Temp\kinect\depth\bmpDepthFrame_" + cur.TimeOfDay.ToString().Replace(':', '.') + ".png";
                string dataFilePath = @"C:\Temp\kinect\depth\depthFrame_" + cur.TimeOfDay.ToString().Replace(':', '.') + ".dat";
                //savePngFrame(myBitmapDepth, imageFilePath);

                //Crop frame to size 180x240
                byte[] croppedDepthFrame = new byte[180 * 240 * 2];

                for (int i = 0; i < 240; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 180 * 2; j += 2)
                    {
                        croppedDepthFrame[i * 180 * 2 + j] = Image.Bits[i * 320 * 2 + j + 69 * 2];
                        croppedDepthFrame[i * 180 * 2 + j + 1] = Image.Bits[i * 320 * 2 + j + 1 + 69 * 2];
                        //Console.Write((i * 180 * 2 + j) + "-" + (i * 180 * 2 + j + 69*2) +", ");
                    }
                    //Console.WriteLine();
                }
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(dataFilePath, FileMode.Create);
                fs.Write(croppedDepthFrame, 0, croppedDepthFrame.Length);
                fs.Close();
            }

            savedDepth = true;
        }
    }
```

Thank You for the help.
This is what I have so far

```
void nui_DepthImageReady(object sender, DepthImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!savedDepth)
        {
            short[] pixelData;
            bool receivedData = false;
            using (DepthImageFrame depthImageFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame())
            {
                if (depthImageFrame != null)
                {
                    if (pixelData == null) //allocate the first time
                    {
                        pixelData = new short[depthImageFrame.PixelDataLength];
                    }
                    depthImageFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(pixelData);
                    receivedData = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    // apps processing of image data took too long; it got more than 2 frames behind.
                    // the data is no longer avabilable.
                }
            }
            if (receivedData)
            {
                byte[] convertedDepthFrame = convertDepthFrame(Image.bits);

                depth.Source = BitmapSource.Create(Image.Width, Image.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, convertedDepthFrame, Image.Width * 4);

                ++totalFrames;

                DateTime cur = DateTime.Now;
                if (cur.Subtract(lastTime) > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                {
                    int frameDiff = totalFrames - lastFrames;
                    lastFrames = totalFrames;
                    lastTime = cur;
                    frameRate.Text = frameDiff.ToString() + " fps";
                }

                if (subscribed)
                {
                    //byte[] ColoredBytes = GenerateColoredBytes(e.ImageFrame);
                    //create an image based on the colored bytes
                    BitmapSource myBitmapDepth = BitmapSource.Create(Image.Width, Image.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, convertedDepthFrame, Image.Width * PixelFormats.Bgr32.BitsPerPixel / 8);
                    string imageFilePath = @"C:\Temp\kinect\depth\bmpDepthFrame_" + cur.TimeOfDay.ToString().Replace(':', '.') + ".png";
                    string dataFilePath = @"C:\Temp\kinect\depth\depthFrame_" + cur.TimeOfDay.ToString().Replace(':', '.') + ".dat";
                    //savePngFrame(myBitmapDepth, imageFilePath);

                    //Crop frame to size 180x240
                    byte[] croppedDepthFrame = new byte[180 * 240 * 2];

                    for (int i = 0; i < 240; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 180 * 2; j += 2)
                        {
                            croppedDepthFrame[i * 180 * 2 + j] = Image.Bits[i * 320 * 2 + j + 69 * 2];
                            croppedDepthFrame[i * 180 * 2 + j + 1] = Image.Bits[i * 320 * 2 + j + 1 + 69 * 2];
                            //Console.Write((i * 180 * 2 + j) + "-" + (i * 180 * 2 + j + 69*2) +", ");
                        }
                        //Console.WriteLine();
                    }
                    FileStream fs = new FileStream(dataFilePath, FileMode.Create);
                    fs.Write(croppedDepthFrame, 0, croppedDepthFrame.Length);
                    fs.Close();
                }
            }
            savedDepth = true;
        }
    }
```

Image.Bits has no definition in the new SDK for kinect or Image.Width, Image.Height
These are the errors that are happening so I dont know how to convert the code to get the same info.

Comment: What errors do you see?  What have you tried that hasn't worked?  Which lines are causing you grief?

Comment: Sorry I should be more in depth. PlanarImage is not in the new SDK for the Kinect. So anything with Image does not work. Fpr example byte[] convertedDepthFrame = convertDepthFrame(Image.Bits); Bits is not recognized.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal?  Have you looked at the different 1.5 examples?  http://kinectforwindows.codeplex.com/

Comment: My ultimate goal is to collect data from motion that occurs. Meaning when a person moves. I want the time the motion occured, what body part of the depth image move and how much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm comparing your sample to a sample in the Kinect 1.5 SDK samples, and it appears that what you've called `Image` may be the same as `pixelData`.  I don't see where `Image` was defined though, so I'm guessing.  Does this help?

Comment: I think the problem is in comparing the two I cant get the same or I dont know how to get the same information from 'Image' for 'pixelData'. 'Image' is defined as a 'PlanarImage' I did not convert it in the second code

Comment: I see that defined at the top.  Thanks for pointing it out.  What are you trying to compute from the data in `Image`?  What is the ultimate goal of your app?